# Building a simple CMS to manage mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, content-management

I want to build a simple CMS system that would be directly connected to my remote database (mysql) and be able to add,delete/update fields/records.

**Are there any examples of this, tutorials? where should I start?**

I'm assuming the language would be php? (Are there any free scripts that does this already?). I would like to build my own regardless.

Comment: [phpMyAdmin](http://phpmyadmin.net/) does this.

Answer (score 4):

Use [adminer](http://adminer.org) or [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php)

You don't need to make your own. They are both opensource so you can go through it and browser around code

Easy example code (show tables & allow to delete tables)

```
<?php
if ($_GET['del']){
    mysql_query("DROP TABLE ".$_GET['del']);
    echo "done";
}

if ($_POST['password']){
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) or die("Wrong details");
    mysql_select_db($_POST['db']) or die("Wrong database");
}


if ($con){
    $result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        echo "<br/>Table ".$row[0]." (<a href='?del=".$row[0]."'>Delete</a>)";
    }
    die();
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">
Username: <input name="username" /><br />
Password: <input name="password" /><Br />
Database: <input name="db" /><br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I already have phpMyAdmin but want something simpler, maybe a login form then a view with the actual table where the player can add/remove tables (something really simple).

Comment: @SpikeLee: added code for you. show, delete tables

Comment: As i said i'm new to this however - when i run that script i get prompted to enter the username,password and db. Then a message saying "delete" appears without showing any tables. You have any tutorials i could look at - helping me achieve something that can display the table fields, add/delete and update? (or pointing me on the right path).

Comment: you will see list of tables if you have any tables in that database. Edited my script

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you read up on MySQL injection to ensure a undesirable visitor cannot inject malicious queries into your database.

I would recommend PHP as I find it goes hand in hand with MySQL

Take a look at this to get you started: http://phpminiadmin.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -1):

If you still want to make your own tools for managing MySQL dbs start by making a decision about what language you want to develop these tools with.

.NET/C# combined with WPF can be a great a solution a desktop based one of course but it will do.

Learning is never annoying.

Comment: I was thinking of going with php, although i never done it before it seems rather simple. But as i said it would be much simpler if i could have a look at some tutorials/examples of implementations? (if such a thing exists)

Comment: If you want a desktop-based solution, go with HeidiSQL. http://www.heidisql.com/